# `python -m unittest discover` does not discover tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, unittest2

Python's unittest discover does not find my tests!

I have been using nose to discover my unit tests and it is working fine. From the top level of my project, if I run `nosetests` I get:

```
Ran 31 tests in 0.390s
```

Now that Python 2.7 unittest [has discovery](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery), I have tried using

```
python -m unittest discover
```

but I get

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

My directory structure is:

```
myproj/
    reporter/
    __init__.py
    report.py
    [other app modules]
        tests/
        __init__.py
        test-report.py
        [other test modules]
```

Do you have any ideas why unittest's discovery algorithm can't find the tests?

I'm using Python 2.7.1 and nose 1.0.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: I just found that the tests are discovered if I rename `test-report.py` to `test_report.py`. Unless someone can shed some light on this, I'll file a bug report to the unittest module maintainer.

Comment: I surprised that this works in nose, since test-report would not be importable.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The behaviour is intentional, but the documentation could make this clearer. If you look at the first paragraph in the test discovery section, it says:

> For a project’s tests to be compatible with test discovery they must all be importable from the top level directory of the project (in other words, they must all be in Python packages).

A corollary to that is that the file names must also be valid Python module names. `test-report.py` fails that test, since `test-report` is not a legal Python identifier.

A docs bug suggesting that this be mentioned explicitly in the documentation for the `-p` pattern option would probably be a good way forward.

Comment: Also note the default discovery pattern looks for test-modules prefixed with the string "test" ... This is what got me.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say we must prefix the test module with "test_" keyword?

Comment: Another gotcha I've hit in the past is having tests with invalid module names. Specifically putting a `.` in e.g. `test_this_works_with_version_9.1` is an invalid module name so will be ignored. Running the file directly works, since the OS has no problems with it.
TLDR: Don't forget to avoid `.` in your module names (and other invalid characters)

Comment: Missing `__init__.py` can also be a reason why some level is not a python package.

Comment: I also had problems that I used unit test module names that were appended with "_test" instead of being preppended... (i.e. "data_convert_test" would not be discovered while "test_data_convert" was discovered and ran successfully)

Comment: It is nowhere in the document, but it seems that only files starts with "test" would be discovered. Also, any import in __init__.py could cause the test to be run multiple times. That module is not well maintained.

Comment: Creating `__init__.py` in the tests directory worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

I had this problem because some directories in a project were missing `__init__.py`. I thought I don't need them in Python 3.7.

Just add `__init__.py` to *every* directory and `python3 -m unittest` will find tests automatically.

Comment: Slight nitpick, but OP did have `__init__.py` in the tests directory.

Answer (score 16):

As someone relatively new to Python, the naming convention in the docs implied the opposite. Ben's comment was very helpful: the default discovery pattern looks for test-modules prefixed with the string "test"

I thought the introspection would just look for class names and not require a specific file naming convention.

Here is what the docs say:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html
python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "*_test.py"
I couldn't get this to work, but by changing my file names to be "test_*.py" - success!

Comment: This work! But where in the documentation does it say we must prefix the test module with "test_" keyword?

Comment: `python -m unittest -h` says for `-p pattern` under "Alternative Usage": `Pattern to match test files ('test*.py' default)`

Comment: To be super specific, to get this to work with "*_test" you need to run it as `python -m unittest discover -p '*_test.py'` when you run your tests, instead of just `python -m unittest` which discovers tests with the naming convention of "test_*" automatically. It's a tradeoff that makes sense to me because I would rather see the test files next to the other files because then I can see if I'm missing a test file easier.

Comment: You need "*_test.py" instead of "_test.py"

Answer (score 0):

This got me as well. This explains the unittest discovery in detail https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

To make `python -m unittest` auto find your tests, you need to do 2 things. 1) add a blank `__init__.py` file to the tests folder, and 2) name your test 'test_some_name.py'. `unittest` looks for the file name to **START** with 'test'. You can change that with the '-p' flag if you want, which is explained in the link above.

Here is my folder strucutre.

```
MyProject
  /src
    my_file.py
  /tests
    __init__.py
    test_my_file.py
```

Then I run `'python -m unittest'` from the MyProject directory.

Here is an example of refrencing the src file from test_my_file.py:

```
import unittest
from src import my_file as MF

class TestMyFileMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_some_method(self) :
        self.assertTrue(True)

    #... more tests ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```